# Do you know a flash barcode scanner?

Tags: javascript, flash

For my web project i require a flash barcode scanner.

I did some research but didn't find any usable software.

Do you know an asset written in flash to scan barcodes what i can include into a html document and access with JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just googled a bit.

http://zxing.riaforge.org/

It's a flex project, but I think you can easily embed the generated SWF or AS3 file into your flash project.

Comment: tanks. i dont know anything about flash programming. so i didn't search for actionscript libraries.